# Copy a number starting with 0 in vba and paste is as such

Tags: vba, excel

say  cell A1, A2, A3 contains value "00V", cell An contains value "029"
I'm doing a comparison for consecutive cells in column A like:

If A1 not equal to A2 then ill copy the cell value of A2 and paste it into a new worksheet in Column A first consecutively.

When I compare 00V and 029 (i.e. both are unequal) ill copy 029 and paste into new sheet

But "029" gets pasted as "29"

How do I fix this in Excel vba?

Comment: do you have a copy of your code? I suspect you are using dim value as double or integer. you  just need to use string instead. Please show code and ill confirm

Comment: Ensure the destination cell is formatted as text; or precede your values  with a single quote `'` (This will not show up in the cell, but will show up in the formula bar.  It tells Excel to  treat data as text).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Format(val, "000")` where `val` is the value of whatever you're copying.

Or you could use `rng.NumberFormat = "000"` where `rng` is the destination range of where you're copying the values to.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the target column format to text and then use paste special values.  You'll be able to preserve the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a apostrophe (') in front of the values. When copied, the 0 will be maintained.